# Strip number from a scraped data and store it in a separate variable

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am using the following code for scraping data. And I wish to extract and store numeric data from the strings.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

base_site_1 = "https://www.cartrade.com/buy-used-cars/new-delhi/c#city=10&sc=-1&so=-1&pn=1"

response = requests.get(base_site_1)
response.status_code

html = response.content
html[:100]

html5lib_soup = soup(html, 'html5lib')

with open('cartrade_used_cars_mumbai_html5lib_Parser.html', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(html5lib_soup.prettify('utf-8'))

html5lib_soup

model = []

for i in html5lib_soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'grid_cnt_new'}):
    model.append(i.a.text.strip())

model
```

Output is

```
['2013 Hyundai Verna Fluidic 1.6 VTVT SX',
 '2021 Land Rover Discovery Sport R-Dynamic SE',
 '2011 Hyundai Santro Xing GLS (CNG)',
 '2016 Porsche Cayenne 3.2 V6 Petrol',
 '2010 Hyundai i10 Era',
 '2011 Honda City V MT CNG Compatible',
 '2016 Mercedes-Benz GLE 250 d',
 '2013 Honda Amaze 1.5 S i-DTEC',
 '2013 Maruti Suzuki Estilo LXi BS-IV',
 '2019 Tata Tiago Revotron XZ',
 '2015 Toyota Innova 2.5 G BS IV 7 STR',
 '2009 Honda City 1.5 S MT',
 '2009 Hyundai Santro Xing GLS',
 '2011 Mahindra Scorpio VLX 4WD Airbag BS-IV',
 '2014 Maruti Suzuki Celerio LXi',
 '2014 Hyundai Grand i10 Magna 1.2 Kappa VTVT [2013-2016]',
 '2016 Hyundai Grand i10 Magna 1.2 Kappa VTVT [2017-2020]',
 '2011 Hyundai i10 Sportz 1.2 Kappa2',
 '2016 Ford EcoSport Titanium 1.5L TDCi',
 '2015 Maruti Suzuki Baleno Delta 1.2',
 '2019 Volkswagen Ameo Trendline 1.2L (P)',
 '2010 Honda City 1.5 S MT',
 '2014 Renault Duster 85 PS RxL Diesel',
 '2014 Honda Brio S MT',
 '2017 Maruti Suzuki Vitara Brezza ZDi+ Dual Tone [2017-2018]',
 '2020 Maruti Suzuki Wagon R 1.0 VXI+ (O)',
 '2016 Maruti Suzuki Ciaz ZXI+ AT',
 '2017 Maruti Suzuki Celerio ZXi [2017-2019]',
 '2011 Toyota Corolla Altis 1.8 G',
 '2012 Honda Brio E MT',
 '2013 Toyota Innova 2.5 GX 7 STR BS-III',
 '2018 Maruti Suzuki Swift Lxi (O) [2014-2017]']
```

And I want to strip 2013 from '2013 Hyundai Verna Fluidic 1.6 VTVT SX' and I want to do the same for every string and store the number in a separate variable and display the output which is a collection of all the numbers from each string when needed like this

```
['2013',
 '2021',
 '2011',
 '2016',
 '2010',
 '2011',
 '2016',
 '2013',
 '2013',
 '2019',
 '2015',
 '2009',
 '2009',
 '2011',
 '2014',
 '2014',
 '2016',
 '2011',
 '2016',
 '2015',
 '2019',
 '2010',
 '2014',
 '2014',
 '2017',
 '2020',
 '2016',
 '2017',
 '2011',
 '2012',
 '2013',
 '2018']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to select the first 4 characters of each string and store them in a new list.

```
years = [car[:4] for car in cars]
```

If you want to display the results per line, you can do

```
print(*years, sep="\n")
```